# Problems getting return value from C library wrapped in FFI in Ruby using Python ctypes as example

Tags: python, c, ruby, ffi

**EDIT:** [Documentation for the relevant library methods!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQbNV.jpg)

Full disclosure - I know next to nothing about C/C++ and literally nothing about pointers and buffers and all that fun stuff. Apologies if this is a stupid question, but I've been working on this for hours and haven't got very far at all.

So I have an external C library that I'm referencing from a Ruby script. There's a bunch of different functions which I need to access, and I've got some simple ones working, but I'm struggling with a more complicated function that I need to work.

The good part - I have working example code in Python.

The challenge I'm facing is around the whole buffer side of things using FFI - I've not found a lot of relevant examples on how to make this work, and I'm struggling a bit.

Here's the function I want to replicate in Ruby using FFI:

```
def getActiveID32():
    """
    Will return a tuple consisting number of bits
    read and actual data. Minimum 8 byte of data will
    be returned.
    """
    rawData = ""
    buffer_size = ctypes.c_short(32);
    pcproxlib.GetActiveID32.restype = ctypes.c_short
    # create a buffer of given size to pass it
    # to get the raw data.
    raw_data_tmp = (ctypes.c_ubyte * buffer_size.value)()
    #as per documentation 250 millisecond sleep is required
    # to get the raw data.
    time.sleep(250/1000.0)
    nbBits = pcproxlib.GetActiveID32(raw_data_tmp , buffer_size)
    bytes_to_read = int((nbBits + 7) / 8) ;
    # will read at least 8 bytes
    if bytes_to_read < 8:
        bytes_to_read = 8

    for i in range(0 , bytes_to_read):
        temp_buf = "%02X " % raw_data_tmp[i]
        rawData = temp_buf + rawData
    return (nbBits , rawData)
```

Here's the example code that I have working for the simple functions (eg `BeepNow` but not for this more complicated function, `getActiveID32`.

Included is the code I've been playing with, but that is clearly too simplified, and doesn't work.

```
require 'ffi'

module PCProxLib
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib File.expand_path('lib/32/libhidapi-hidraw.so.0')
  ffi_lib File.expand_path('lib/32/libpcProxAPI.so')
  attach_function :usbConnect, [], :short
  attach_function :getPartNumberString, [], :string
  attach_function :getActiveID32, [:string, :int], :int
  attach_function :getActiveID, [], :int
  attach_function :BeepNow, [:int, :bool], :bool
end

puts PCProxLib.usbConnect()

puts PCProxLib.BeepNow(3, false)

sleep 0.25
buffer = ""
puts PCProxLib.getActiveID32(buffer, 64)
puts buffer
```

Thanks heaps for any help :)

**EDIT:**

Based on @matt's comment, I've revised the code to the following:

```
require 'ffi'

module PCProxLib
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib File.expand_path('lib/32/libhidapi-hidraw.so.0')
  ffi_lib File.expand_path('lib/32/libpcProxAPI.so')
  attach_function :usbConnect, [], :short
  attach_function :USBDisconnect, [], :short
  attach_function :getActiveID32, [:pointer, :int], :int
end

PCProxLib.usbConnect()

puts PCProxLib.getPartNumberString() // verifying connection to reader

def read_card
  sleep 0.5
  buffer = FFI::MemoryPointer.new(:uint8, 32)
  bits_written = PCProxLib.getActiveID32(buffer, 32)
  puts bits_written
  puts buffer.read_bytes(32)
end

20.times { read_card }

PCProxLib.USBDisconnect()
```

When I scan a card (while the code is looping), the `bits_written` value jumps from 0 to 32, which seems good. However the `buffer.read_bytes(32)` value is always null.

I've tried some other MemoryPointer methods (like `read`, `read_string` etc but get the same results.

If I try `.inspect`ing the `buffer.read_bytes(32)`, I get:

```
"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
```

...which is interesting? This is the same, whether I scan a card or not.

Comment: If the buffer contains zeros after the call then that would suggest the function is writing zeros. But I am wondering about the delay you are adding, surely it would make sense for that to be _after_ the call, to give it time to get and write the data?

Comment: @matt yep agreed. Re the delay - good point. I tried moving the delay around, same result unfortunately. I've reached out to the manufacturer for clarification, hopefully they can shed some light...

Comment: @matt I've added a link to the relevant documentation at the top of the question, this may help clarify things?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the function `getActiveID32` has a signature that looks something like

```c
int getActiveID32(uint8_t *buffer, int size)
```

and you would use it by first creating a buffer for it to write into, and then passing a pointer to that buffer and its size as arguments when you call it, something like:

```c
// Define BUFFER_SIZE first.
uint8_t *buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
int bits_written = getActiveID32(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
// There are now bits_written bits in buffer for you to use.
// You will need to call free on buffer when you are finished.
```

With Ruby’s FFI you can do this with a [Pointer](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Pointers). First declare the function to accept a pointer (a string is like a pointer, but in this case we need to use a pointer directly):

```ruby
attach_function :getActiveID32, [:pointer, :int], :int
```

Now when you want to call it, you need to first create a `MemoryPointer` of the desired size, and pass it as the parameter to the function. FFI will then convert this into a pointer to the allocated memory when calling the C function.

```ruby
# Assuming you want a 32 byte buffer.
buffer = FFI::MemoryPointer.new(:uint8, 32)
bits_written = PCProxLib.getActiveID32(buffer, 32)
```

Now `buffer` will contain the data written by the function. You can access this data using the [methods on `MemoryPointer`](https://rubydoc.info/gems/ffi/FFI/MemoryPointer), for example to copy that data into a Ruby (binary) string you can use `buffer.read_bytes(32)`.

`MemoryPointer` will also handle freeing the allocated memory when it is garbage collected.

Comment: Please refer to the edit in the question because comment formatting seems beyond me today. Thanks very much for your help, it's hugely appreciated.